# Script attack on classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have website as Classic ASP as Front end and SQL Server 2005 as Back end.

But I am facing a very strange SQL injection on my back end.

Some type of CSS with HTML with spamming site is appending their code to my website database with each table and with each varchar type columns.

For e.g.

```
</title><style>.am1y{position:absolute;clip:rect(405px,auto,auto,405px);}</style><div class=am1y>same day <a href=http://mazzpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a></div>
```

I Checked My IIS Log It shows me like this

> 2013-06-09 19:15:54 GET
>   /mypage.asp%3C/title%3E%3Cstyle%3E.axo5{position:absolute;clip:rect(404px,auto,auto,404px);}%3C/style%3E%3Cdiv%20class=axo5%3Eapproval%20%3Ca%20href=http:/mazzpaydayloans.com%20%3Epayday%20loans%3C/a%3E%3C/div%3E
>   - - 204.13.205.99 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1)
>   loginfailure=chance=0&bantime=;+ASPSESSIONIDSSDRRCQQ=EDPHPJGCGLMKOADICKHODKBM
>   - www.mysite.com 404 0 281 543 78

On my this selected ASP Page all SQL queries are parametrized.

But still this issue is persists.

MyPage.asp Code

```
new_prot = "http" 
new_https = lcase(request.ServerVariables("HTTPS")) 
if new_https <> "off" then new_prot = "https" 
new_domainname = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") 
new_filename = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") 

set cm1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cm1.ActiveConnection = conn
cm1.commandtype=1
cm1.CommandText ="select * from Table1 where Web=?"

cm1.prepared=true
dim weburl

set weburl=cm1.createparameter(Web_URL,200,,5000)
weburl.value= Server.HtmlEncode(ltrim(rtrim(new_filename)))
cm1.parameters.append weburl


set Mobile = cm1.execute(RecordsAffected,,adCmdText)


do until Mobile.EOF
response.redirect(Mobile.fields("mob"))
loop
```

Comment: PLease post here code of `/mypage.asp` here. Also confirm (check all your site) that injection was only over this page.

Comment: How You parse recieved GET query before passing to SELECT statement?

Comment: Please check code i edited above post.

Comment: Injection was not over this code. As You can see, IIS log record have 404 status (Not found). Try search in IIS log string `'`, `SELECT` and `--`.

Comment: Could that thing in the logs just be a broken link after the infection already occurred? It doesn't have any SQL in it. Unencoded it is `/mypage.asp</title><style>.axo5{position:absolute;clip:rect(404px,auto,auto,404px);}</style><div class=axo5>approval <a href=http:/mazzpaydayloans.com >payday loans</a></div> -`

Comment: The actual attack may well be a post so won't be as easily detectable in the logs. Also it may be on pages of the site that you dont believe are still active or even on an obsolete version of the site if you have other versions up still accesible to the outside world.

Answer (score 2):

First, your query may be parameterised, but you need to impliment a stored procedure, not a straight SQL command.

```
set cm1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cm1.ActiveConnection = conn
cm1.commandtype=1
cm1.CommandText ="select * from Table1 where Web=?"
```

command text is a no no

you need to impliment a stored procedure:

```
CREATE ProcTable 
@ParamWeb INT
as 

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PAgeID = @ParamWeb
```

Then Exec the proc. This prevents injection because the page can ONLY accept the numeric value of the proc, and that will only return the revelant dataset (empty or with rows)

Your command text can have

```
"; any injection script you want"
```

appended

any injection script can contain sqlcmdShell so once the injection has been made the bad guys can return a list of tables, their content, users, user data etc etc

Comment: You right - in common cases this rules should be used. But his code (publicated part) is safe too: as i know, not possible to falsify `Request.ServerVariables` values, because it created ASP engine.

Comment: Ages since I've used classic ASP but at least in `.NET` properly parameterized queries are no more vulnerable to SQL injection than stored procedures. Have you any details of why they would be less secure? One advantage of stored procedures given that the OP apparently does have a SQL injection issue would be that they could then just grant `exec` permissions on those and remove all direct permissions on the base tables.

Comment: @Ian P: How EXACTLY could you append that to the command text? That looks like a parameterized query to me. Can you provide an example?